# What is the logic behind Krugman's argumentation about dumping?

Tags: international-trade, international-economics

I don't quite understand what he is trying to say. As I see it, a lower marginal cost should lead to an increase in export prices, not the opposite.

[image: Krugman aproach]

[image: Figure 8-8]

Comment: The claim is not that the **price** is lower than a firm with lower marginal cost would charge, but that the **markup** (price/marginal cost) is lower than a firm with lower marginal cost would set.

Comment: I says that firm one set an export price that is lower than domestic price.

Comment: You left off the caveat from the middle of the sentence: *net of trade costs*.

Comment: I will grant you that Krugman's book is bad. (At least I did not like it.) He mixes assumptions and consequences, does not indicate when something is to be accepted or can be proven from the previous claims, the proofs are handwavy and it is generally not easy to follow if you want to get a thorough understanding.